# Jade - Template Engine: How to check if a mixin exists

Tags: node.js, pug

> Jade - Template Engine: How to check if a mixin exists

Comment: I don't think you can, but why would you need it to begin with?

Comment: I can tell my situation, basically previous genius front end developer decided to use mixin as a way to pass blocks of html between templates instead of built in `block`. He would declare mixin in parent and use it in child. Now if you wanted to use child template on its own you can't because you are using mixin that doesn't exist. Therefore if i could check if mixin exists i can avoid that error.